# How to pass a list of TIFF files to TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIProcessPages

Tags: java, pdf, tiff, tess4j, leptonica

I am using the Tesseract Java API (tess4J) to convert TIFF files to readable PDFs.

When I have a single source TIFF file, the results have been quite pleasing:

```
        TessResultRenderer renderer = TessAPI1.TessPDFRendererCreate("outpath/my_new_pdf.pdf", dataPath, 0);
        TessAPI1.TessResultRendererInsert(renderer, TessAPI1.TessPDFRendererCreate("output/my_new_pdf.pdf", dataPath, 0));
        int result = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIProcessPages(handle, sourceTiffFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, 0, renderer);
```

However, the [API documentation](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-3.0/net/sourceforge/tess4j/TessAPI1.html#TessBaseAPIProcessPages-net.sourceforge.tess4j.ITessAPI.TessBaseAPI-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-net.sourceforge.tess4j.ITessAPI.TessResultRenderer-) states that you should be able to supply a list of files, as well as just a single file: **Recognizes all the pages in the named file, as a multi-page tiff or list of filenames, or single image...**

This would be very handy as I would like to pass in several TIFFS to produce a multi-page PDF, one page per image, but I haven't yet been able to work out how to pass in a list of images. The obvious first attempt was to pass in a comma separated list of absolute file paths to the TIFFs, where the above example passes in `sourceTiffFile.getAbsolutePath()`, but the result is a very small, apparently corrupt PDF file.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a filelist with each entry on a separate line (i.e, delimited by \n character).